# Android: Changing activity in the background

Tags: android

I want to make 2 pages in my app:

1. **Main page** - get push notifications and show data
2. **Chat page** - get push notifications for the chat

Is it possible to run 2 activities at the same time (both will have a `BroadcastReceiver` for the push) and to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to switch between activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for all the operations you run in the background.

(A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. You can simply switch between activity and activity can perform action from background also. But it is always better to use service for background works.

Comment: activity has ui elements so can you update ui from a background thread directly?